# Command Not Found when trying to use the "android" bash command?

Tags: android, bash, shell, command-line

I am trying to use the android command like this

```
:~ antonpug$ android list targets
```

But it doesn't work? I get "command not found". What am I doing wrong?

I installed the SDK. Using Mac OS X.

Comment: what base os u r using ? window or linux or mac ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the android platform-tools and tools paths to your systems PATH variable. Modify your .profile or .bash_rc file to append the path to the directories in the root of your sdk folder.